# display first sale product in shop

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

how can i improve the code to work? I want to sort the products by the products on sale ... like the first time to display the products on sale ... and after the rest.

```
function catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    if( !is_product_category() ){
        return $args;
    }
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['meta_key'] = '_sale_price';
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'catalog_ordering_args', 20, 1 );
```

source: [How to get sale product first on category listing page woocommerce?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383452/how-to-get-sale-product-first-on-category-listing-page-woocommerce?fbclid=IwAR1StiOgRTjKSc9vTohtMZncTiTYasal9fI36baKHZX5vu6e0XCF1L3-DTY)